# Integration by part on weak derivative

Tags: partial-differential-equations

As you know if $f,\ g\in C^1(\overline{U})$, where $U$ is bounded in ${\bf R}^n$ and if $f,\ g$ have compact support in $U$, then $$ \int_{{\bf R}^n} f(x)_{x_i}g(x)\ dx =-\int_{{\bf R}^n} f(x) g(x)_{x_i}\ dx $$

If $f$ and $g$ are weak derivatives of $u$ and $w$, then how can we prove this ?

(That is, $ f_{x_i}=v $ if for any $\phi \in C_c^\infty(U)$, $ \int_{{\bf R}^n} f(x)\phi_{x_i}(x)\ dx = -
\int_{{\bf R}^n} v(x)\phi(x)\ dx$ )

Comment: You need to impose some more conditions on $f$ and $g$ because in general the product of 2 locally integrable functions will not be locally integrable.

Comment: Please Give me an example i think that the converse holds in some case for instance f(x)=1/x

Comment: Multiply $\frac1{\sqrt{x}}$ by $\frac1{\sqrt{x}}$.